# gedit - ENable middle-mouse copy/paste

Tags: copy-paste, gedit

On Ubuntu 20 gedit, I want to copy/paste with middle-mouse button (MMB) as such:
highlight a string, move the cursor and click with MMB to paste it again.

However, I didn't find this setting in gnome-tweaks - how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: This should be enabled by default, if you try simply pasting with middle click, doesn't-it work?

Comment: I agree it is horribly annoying. An beyond mere habits, often very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the problem with gedit is that when you click again somewhere else (without any selection), your selected text will be replaced!
So, when you select something, just use the middle-click to paste the selection.